# What are the operators (.&.) and (.|.)?

Tags: haskell

I have come across the operators `.&.` and `.|.`, but I cannot seem to find anything about them on the internet. What does these operators do?

Comment: Likely these are for the [*bitwise* and](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:.-38-.) and the [*bitwise* or](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:.-124-.).

Answer (score 7):

> What does these operators do?

Since every software package can define its own operators, one can not tell this with certainty. If you use [*Hoogle*](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(.%26.)), then definitions appear for a *bitwise* and, but also as a combinator of two testable properties.

You thus will need to look to the imports at the top of the file. If you are importing `Data.Bits`, then it is the [*bitwise and* **`(.&.) :: Bits a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:.-38-.). If on the other hand you imported `Test.QuickCheck`, it is a [*nondeterministic choice* **`(.&.) :: (Testable prop1, Testable prop2) => prop1 -> prop2 -> Property`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:.-38-.).